# Trying to eliminate Temporary Tables MYSQL and combine process into one statement if possible

Tags: php, mysql, performance, temp-tables

I have an application that is tracking sales for 11 salesmen.  This is a simple enough process except that sales can be shared amongst salesman which cuts their sale value in half.  Meaning if two salesmen share a job that has a value of $100 then each salesman only counts $50 sales value for themselves.  Below is the code I am currently using to accomplish this process but it seems clunky and performance is a bit sluggish for my taste.  Is it possible to combine this into a single process and eliminate the need for a Temporary Table (I also saw somewhere you shouldn't use Temporary Tables in production)

```
$sql = "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS newbalancetbl" ;
  mysqli_query ($db, $sql ) or ( "Error " . mysqli_error () ) ;

  $newBalances = "
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newbalancetbl (
      `custid` int NOT NULL,
      `assigned` int NOT NULL,
      `newBalance` double,
      PRIMARY KEY(custid)
    )
  ";

   mysqli_query($db, $newBalances) or die ("Sql error : ".mysqli_error());

  $year = date("Y");
  $start = "01/01/".$year;
  $today = date("Y-m-d");
  $first = $year."-01-01";

  $assignments = "SELECT leadid, price
                  FROM jobbooktbl 
                  WHERE convertdate >= '".$first."' AND convertdate<='".$today."' AND (status=4 OR status=6 OR status=7 OR status=8 OR status=11)";
  $assignmentsqry = mysqli_query($db,$assignments);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($assignmentsqry)) {
    $custid = $row["leadid"];
    $price = $row["price"];

    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO newbalancetbl (custid, newBalance) VALUES (?,?)");
    $statement->bind_param('id', $custid, $price);
    $statement->execute();
  }

  $sqlnewbal = "SELECT a.custid, COUNT(a.custid) AS assCnt
                  FROM assignmentstbl a, newbalancetbl b
                  WHERE a.custid=b.custid
                  GROUP BY a.custid";
  $qrynewbal = mysqli_query($db,$sqlnewbal);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qrynewbal)) {
    $custid = $row['custid'];
    // $paid = $row["sumAmnt"];
    $assigned = $row['assCnt'];

    $usqlUpdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE newbalancetbl SET assigned=? WHERE custid=?");
    $usqlUpdate->bind_param('ii',$assigned,$custid);
    $usqlUpdate->execute();
  }

  $sqlnewbal = "SELECT *
                  FROM newbalancetbl";
  $qrynewbal = mysqli_query($db,$sqlnewbal);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qrynewbal)) {
    $custid = $row['custid'];
    $assigned = $row['assigned'];
    $newBalance = $row['newBalance'];
    $newBal = $newBalance/$assigned;
    $newBal - number_format($newBal,2);

    $usqlUpdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE newbalancetbl SET newBalance=? WHERE custid=?");
    $usqlUpdate->bind_param('di',$newBal,$custid);
    $usqlUpdate->execute();
  }

  $salesArray = [];

  $tesql = "SELECT SUM(n.newBalance) AS newB, u.username
            FROM newbalancetbl n
            INNER JOIN assignmentstbl a 
              ON a.custid=n.custid 
            INNER JOIN usertbl u 
              ON a.userid=u.userid 
            -- WHERE u.salesman=1
            GROUP BY a.userid
            ORDER BY newB DESC";
  $teresult = mysqli_query($db,$tesql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($teresult)) {
    $user = $row['username'];
    $sales = $row['newB'];

    array_push($salesArray, [$user,floatval($sales)]);
  }

  $arrayCount = count($salesArray);

  $total_sales = 0;
  $total_sales = array_sum( array_map(function($element){
                  return $element[1];
                }, 
             $salesArray));
  $pretotal_sales = number_format($total_sales, 2);
  $total_sales = '$' . number_format($total_sales, 2);
```

Table Schema:

**jobbooktbl**
[image]

**assignmentstbl**
[image]

Comment: just an observation - initial `mysqli_query ($db, $sql ) or ( "Error " . mysqli_error () ) ;` ~ is missing either `die` or `exit`

Comment: Tricky question, there isn't anything against temporary tables although I've generally only seen them in a stored procedure.  I'm trying to get your goal here. Is it a report of the balance each salesman has got?

Comment: Mmm, yeah, maybe a few subqueries into the mix. If you've got the schemas of the tables invovled that could help

Comment: @RichardHousham basically I am outputting a multidemensional array with salesman name and that salesmans total.  I will update the question with the table schemas.

Comment: how about constructing a small example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? it's really hard to get through all those queries and schemas in ones mind :)

Comment: What the code in `$newBal = $newBalance/$assigned;` loop suppose to do? It makes no sense unless `jobbooktbl.leadid` is unique.

Comment: @AlexBlex `jobbooktbl.leadid` is unique.  It returns a salesmans value of a shared job.  If they are the only salesman on the job and the job was $200 dollars then they would be credited $200 (200/1=200) if they shared the job with another salesman, meaning there are two salesman assigned then they would only be credited with $100 (200/2=100)

Comment: Fair enough, one more question.What kind of error you get in `$newBal = $newBalance/$assigned;` when `assigned` remains null?

Comment: The SQL in the question returns no error.  I am trying to eliminate the use of a temporary table in the production and to increase performance throughout the app.  This is just one report that is using this style of computing there are several more so the performance is terrible.

Comment: I get it, and am trying to help. I just don't see how it works when there is nobody assigned to the job. The inner join comes in play in the final sql only, so I am trying to figure out what is missed in the question that makes the code running without errors. The code as it is posted results with division by 0 error in `$newBal = $newBalance/$assigned;` when there assignmentstbl has no rows for a custid.

Comment: There is always someone assigned to the job.  The user is restricted to only submit jobs with someone assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go over the code to understand what it does, and suggest modifications along the way.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newbalancetbl (
  custid     int NOT NULL,
  assigned   int NOT NULL,
  newBalance double,
  PRIMARY KEY(custid)
) ENGINE=Memory
```

OK. The table seems small, so you might want to use ENGINE=Memory to make it faster. Also, consider using a DECIMAL type instead of DOUBLE. This is not mandatory, but it avoids rounding error headaches.

Anyway. Your first query. Filling your table using php while() loops is slow and unnecessary. Simply do:

```
INSERT INTO newbalancetbl (custid, newBalance)
SELECT leadid, price
FROM jobbooktbl 
WHERE convertdate BETWEEN '$first' AND '$today' 
AND status IN (4,6,7,8,11);
```

Note the use of IN() which is more readable. Also, the BETWEEN. INSERT INTO SELECT will be much faster than looping through query results in php. Also, I don't see "assigned" and "newBalance" in the inserted columns, yet the table does not specify any default values. You should make the default value explicit.

Now, the next query is:

```
SELECT custid, COUNT(*) AS assCnt
FROM assignmentstbl a JOIN newbalancetbl b USING (custid)
GROUP BY custid
```

I changed the ugly old JOIN syntax with the correct one (since about 1999). Also, COUNT(col) counts the rows where "col" is not null. So COUNT(a.custid) it implies that "a.custid" can actually be null. Since it can't, this syntax is just confusing. I replace it with count(*).

Then you look over the results in PHP, and do "UPDATE newbalancetbl SET assigned=$assCnt WHERE custid=?"

You should decide whether to use the name "assCnt" or "assigned". I like the first one better, since it is a count, having "cnt" in the name makes it less confusing. Now, this loop is unnecessary, we could use a single UPDATE with a JOIN, or better, build the values into the rable right from the start. Thus, the first query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO newbalancetbl (custid, newBalance, assigned)
SELECT j.leadid, j.price, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM assignmentstbl a WHERE a.custid=j.leadid) AS assigned
FROM jobbooktbl j
WHERE j.convertdate BETWEEN '$first' AND '$today' 
AND j.status IN (4,6,7,8,11);
```

I used a subselect. Feel free to use a JOIN instead.

Next query. I will ignore "$newBal - number_format($newBal,2);" which does nothing since you used "-" instead of "="... this would be solved by using a NUMERIC format, or just use this:

```
UPDATE newbalancetbl 
SET newBalance=ROUND(newBalance/assigned, 2)
```

Another php loop eliminated. But we can eliminate the update, and the temp table too while we're at it.

```
SELECT 
    j.leadid AS custid, 
    ROUND( j.price / (SELECT count(*) FROM assignmentstbl a WHERE a.custid=j.leadid), 2) AS newBalance
FROM jobbooktbl j
WHERE j.convertdate BETWEEN '$first' AND '$today' 
AND j.status IN (4,6,7,8,11);
```

This should give the exact same results as what the temp table contained, minus the "assigned" column, which is not used in the rest of the code anyway, so we can drop it. Now, let's insert this into the next query...

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(n.newBalance), 2) AS newB, u.username
FROM (
    SELECT 
        j.leadid AS custid, 
        j.price / (SELECT count(*) FROM assignmentstbl a WHERE a.custid=j.leadid) AS newBalance
    FROM jobbooktbl j
    WHERE j.convertdate BETWEEN '$first' AND '$today' 
    AND j.status IN (4,6,7,8,11)
    ) n
    JOIN assignmentstbl a USING (custid)
    JOIN usertbl u USING (userid)
    -- WHERE u.salesman=1
    GROUP BY a.userid
    ORDER BY newB DESC
```

This should do what you want. I moved the ROUND in the outside query.

Comment: Wow this is extremely detailed and helpful, let me look at this and see if I can get it working.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No dice, I am getting NULL value returns and no errors.

Comment: You'll have to do it step by step to see where I screwed up then ;)

Comment: I was able to get this working and it is returning the numbers as expected!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With assumptions *there is always someone assigned to the job*, and many others implied in the question, the single query could be:

```
SELECT SUM(n.newBalance) AS newB, u.username, u.userid
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        j.leadid as custid,
        (j.price / COUNT(*)) as newBalance
    FROM jobbooktbl j
    INNER JOIN assignmentstbl a 
      ON a.custid = j.leadid
    WHERE j.convertdate >= ? 
      AND j.convertdate <= ? 
    GROUP BY 1
    ) n
INNER JOIN assignmentstbl a 
  ON a.custid=n.custid 
INNER JOIN usertbl u 
  ON a.userid=u.userid 
GROUP BY u.userid
ORDER BY newB DESC;
```

The `n` subquery calculates average price

> If they are the only salesman on the job and the job was $200 dollars then they would be credited $200 (200/1=200) if they shared the job with another salesman, meaning there are two salesman assigned then they would only be credited with $100 (200/2=100)

assuming that if there are 4 salesmen assigned to the same job, they'll get $50 each.

Comment: I tried this out swapping the ?'s with the date variables and received `null` response and no errors.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Check the update. It's quite bad it did not show the error.

Comment: This is returning values now.  But some of the numbers are off from what I would expect.  I have three salesman that are accurate and 6 that are above and below what I would expect them to be.  I am trying to understand the statement above but as I am not totally sure what I am looking at it is hard to figure out where this might be calculating incorrectly.

Comment: Fair enough. As I stated, it is based on too many assumptions, so please try to add some data to the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96bef8/2 to reproduce unexpected results, and comment back here with the url that exposes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of stab at this

```
SELECT name,SUM(
     SELECT  (
         SELECT price/
         (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM jobs WHERE job.ID = Assignments.jobId) 
               FROM jobs WHERE 
                   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM assignment WHERE salesman.ID = assignment.salesmanId) > 0)
      )
    ) AS commission 
    FROM salesman.
```

Right so select all the saleman, get the price from all the jobs he is part of. Divide that price by the number of people on the job. The table might have changed names but on the whole I think that's what you are going for.

Comment: I received the following error `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT ( SELECT price / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM jobbooktbl WHERE ' at line 2` As I am still trying to understand the query I am not sure what the error means.

Comment: the sqlfiddle thing could help here.

Comment: It's difficult without seeing the query and the schema, with long queries like this I would start small so, get the sum of the assignments assigned to the salesman (or people).

Comment: I am working to try and put together an sqlfiddle, I am not very advanced with sql and haven't ever used sqlfiddle before.

Comment: Yeah same here, I think if you right click the table in your mysql editor (workbench) then you can copy the sql and paste it in.

Comment: Instead of `WHERE  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM assignment WHERE salesman.ID = assignment.salesmanId) > 0)`, use `WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  assignment WHERE salesman.ID = assignment.salesmanId )`; it will be faster, perhaps a lot faster.